# jquery on submit form search for its corresponding div and hide form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple forms in same page with submit , i want to hide the form after form submit and display a link for the respective forms
Below is the html i have the same class name for all the forms
and for the submit class also.

```
<div id="wpcf7-f63-p1-o1">
<form name="" class="wpcf7-form" action="" method = "post"> 
<input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" />
<input type="text" name="email" value="" size="40" />
<input type="submit" value="Send" class="but" />
 </form>
</div>

<div id="wpcf7-f63-p1-o2">

 <form name="" class="" action="" method = "post"> 
<input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" />
<input type="text" name="email" value="" size="40" />
 <input type="submit" value="Send" class="but" />
 </form>
</div>
```

i tried the below code

```
<script> 
jQuery(".wpcf7-form").submit(function() 
{ 
jQuery("^wpcf7-f63-p1-").hide(); 
});
</script>';
```

Comment: are you submitting the form using ajax otherwise this wont work because the page is always fresh after page refresh.

Comment: what is the error then?

Answer (score 0):

In your example typed:

`jQuery("^wpcf7-f63-p1-").hide();`

i think should be:

`jQuery("#wpcf7-f63-p1-o1").hide();`

Answer (score 0):

Use this on form submit

```
 $('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
      $form = $(this).parent();
      $('<p><a href="#">link to form</a></p>').insertBefore($form);
      $form.hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for jquery  [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) ?

you could do something like this:

```js
  $('form').submit(function(){

    $(this).find('.myForm').hide();
    $(this).find('.link').show();
  }
```

```css
.link {
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="" class="" action="" method = "post"> 
  <div class="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" />
    <input type="text" name="email" value="" size="40" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="but" />
  </div>
  <a class="link" href="#">Link</a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

ah error on your jquery selector, change your js to:

```
jQuery(".wpcf7-form").submit(function() 
{ 
jQuery("[id^='wpcf7-f63-p1-']").hide() 
return false;
});
```

working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1u0ozku2/) code

NB. *you may need to delete the `return false`, I added it to see the elements getting disappeared after submit.*